# creating a new dataframe based on differen data in rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, tidyverse

I'm moving an operation from Excel Power Query to R, which is much faster.  The result is I have a data frame with thousands of rows, however, I'm looking to create a sample data frame that includes one row for every different option (factor level)for columns 5:10 of 15 columns, so people can manually test every option (like a truth table?)

I could manually do this, but I wondered if I could do it automatically.

```
    col1     col2       col3
    name     option1    option2
    name2    option1    option2
    name3    option1    option2
    name4    option2    option1
```

would be converted into a data frame like this:

```
    col1     col2       col3
    name     option1    option2
    name4    option2    option1
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: see `?duplicated`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% distinct(col2, col3, .keep_all=T)

#    col1    col2    col3
# 1  name option1 option2
# 2 name4 option2 option1
```

If you want to use `distinct` only for a subset of columns, you can match first a regex:

```
d %>% 
    select(matches("[5-10]|[1]")) %>%  # this selects only rows from 5 to 10 or 1 in the name
    distinct(.keep_all=T)
```

This will have your first row `"col1"`, and all the rows `"col5"` to `"col10"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  In my data frame I end up with 19 thousand rows still (from 39,000) I'm after a table with about 100 - 200 lines, but perhaps my maths is way off.  rather than have a new row for every distinct option, have rows which may take care of many options per row, so reducing the number of lines...does that make any sense?

Comment: mm no, I'm sorry but you need to be more clear. Try updating your question with a reproducible example where you show what you expect.